# interpreting string literal

Tags: c++, c

I had method which required `const unsigned char *` as parameter, e.g.

```
func(const unsigned char* p);
```

I called it like this: `func("\x34\x21\x00\x00");` (value passed is decimal 8500 in little endian).

*My question is why I could pass `"\x34\x21\x00\x00"` as `char*`?*

Let me give brief explanation and please correct me if I am wrong.

What was passed to the function **was the address of the first byte** of the string "\x34\x21\x00\x00". The string "\x34\x21\x00\x00" **is stored in memory**, and basically I passed the address of the first byte of this string. Am I right?

Comment: is that C or C++ ? looks C to me.

Comment: @concept3d: is there smth here which is not valid in C++?

Comment: yes. This *will* give an error in C++. In C pointers can be implicitly casted. Just tried on both compilers to make sure, check my answer.

Comment: @concept3d: ok, how'd you do this on C++? cast on a separate line? and then pass to the function the pointer..?

Comment: @user2568508: Yes, I overlooked it at first too. `"\x34\x21\x00\x00"`is implicitly typed as `const char*`. Passing a pointer of `const char*` requires, depending on the implementation, an implicit conversion to `const unsigned char*`, which is illegal.

Comment: Another difference between C and C++ would be that string literals in C are of type `char*` (which is stupid) and in C++ they are of type `const char*`.

Comment: @thokra: It doesn't depend on the implementation. `char` and `unsigned char` are distinct types, so that the pointer conversion requires a cast, whether or not `char` is signed.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: My bad. I think I misinterpreted $3.9.1-1 where it says that "a plain char object can take on either the same values as a signed char or an unsigned char; which one is implementation-defined." and took that for "if the impl. says the values are equal to the unsigned representation, implicit conversion from `char` to `unsigned char` works." However, the types are still distinct, no matter how they represent values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right.  It doesn't matter what the string contains - you're passing the address of its first byte.

Answer (score 1):

This is legal in C, pointer will be implicitly casted. In C++ though this will give an error (just tried in MSVC2010).

Comment: To clarify, a string literal such as `"abc"` is of type `char*`. Implicit casts between `unsigned char*` and `char*` are not allowed in C++, and bad practice in C. However, the essence of the OP's question is about where parameters are stored in memory. So this answer would probably have been better as a comment.

Comment: Although you're right, Lundin, in part actually proposed an answer worthy of, well, an answer. You could've just put the same info in a comment.

Comment: @thokra Yes, I re-read the question, you are right the question was about memory and not data types.

Comment: @Lundin That's what I meant in my answer, but it seems it should have been a comment.